# how to link enum class in @return? in Doxygen, VScode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, enums, documentation, doxygen

I am trying to write a code in Doxygen style documentation.

## Problem

I want to link enum class `results`. But link is not seen in VScode when mouse is on function name.

### Code

I made small test example for question :)

`test.h`

```cpp
/*! A global enum */
enum class results {
    ERROR = -1,
    FAILED = 0,
    SUCCESS = 1
};

/*!
 * @brief Doxygen test (Doxygen Documentation Generator v1.3.2)
 * 
 * @return #results 
 */
results doSomething();
```

### Screenshot

[image: Doxygen Question]

### What I read

https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/autolink.html

I think I did the same thing `#GlobEnum` from this document, but not working.
And also `::GlobEnum` (`::results` in this example) neither :(

## Question

Is there possible way to link enum class in `@return` ?

Comment: Looks like a problem in VS Code, like you expected, as in doxygen (1.9.2) it is shown properly. I don't the version mentioned in your example (1.3.2, from June 15, 2003) is correct , when it is you should update doxygen for sure.

Comment: @albert Well, the version that I wrote ```v1.3.2``` is **Doxygen Documentation Generator**, VSCode Extension name. I think it is not a Doxygen version. (And also I don't know how to check the version of Doxygen in VSCode when I put cursor **above the function**.) According to [Doxygen Documentation Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschlosser.doxdocgen), v1.3.2 is updated at 2021-05-29. So, I don't think this is version problem sir.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know VS Code or the used "Doxygen Documentation Generator" but I guess that it just adds doxygen style documentation tags and in the code these are interpreted by VS Code and not by doxygen (otherwise it would require to run doxygen with each change). The `#results` should result in a link to `results` but probably VS Code has no idea, yet, about how to do it or it is a missing thing in the VS Code implementation of `@return`. Question is what happens with the link when it is outside the `@returns`.

Comment: @albert Thanks for your interest. [Image outside then @returns](https://i.imgur.com/dVruY63.png) is like this image. Not working at all.. I think the only conclusion that we can have is VScode doesn't use doxygen **purely** :(

Comment: I don't think that VS Code doxygen documentation generator uses doxygen at all just creates the comments. I assume the the plugin is from https://github.com/cschlosser/doxdocgen, so maybe best to drop an issue there as well.